# Using embeddings for non-language concepts?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, embedding, one-hot-encoding, data-representation

Does it make sense to use an embedding instead large one-hot encoded vectors representing, say, car makes and models? Also, what would the embedding represent conceptually? How similar a Ford F-150 is to a Toyota Tacoma, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense.

You can think of embeddings as a representation of your input in a different space. Sometimes you want to perform dimensionality reduction, hence your embedding has lower dimensionality than your input. Other times, you simply want your embedding to be very descriptive of your input, so that your model, say a Neural Network, can easily distinguish it from all other inputs (this is especially useful in classification task).

As you can see, an embedding is just a vector that describes your input better than the input itself. In this context, we generally refer to embeddings with the word ***features***.

---

But, maybe, what you're asking is a bit different. You want to know if an embedding can express similarity between cars. Theoretically, yes. Suppose you have the following embeddings:

```
Car A: [0 1]
Car B: [1 0]
```

The first element of the embedding is the maker. `0` stands for Toyota and `1` stands for Ferrari. The second element is the model. `0` stands for F-150 and `1` stands for 458 Italia. How can you compute similarity between these two cars?

**Cosine similarity**
Basically, you compute cosine of the angle between these two vectors in the embedding space. Here the embeddings are 2-dimensional, hence we are in a plane. Moreover, the two embeddings are orthogonal, thus the angle between them is 90° and the cosine 0. So their similarity is 0: they are not similar at all!

Suppose you have:

```
Car A: [1 0]
Car B: [1 1]
```

In this case the maker is the same. Although the model is different, you might expect these two cars to be more similar than the previous two. If you compute the cosine of the angle between their embeddings, you get around 0.707 which is greater than 0. These two cars are indeed more similar.

Obvoiusly, it's not so easy. It all depends on how you design your model and how the embeddings are learned, i.e. which data you provide as input to your system.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Yes it makes sense. No it's not the same as the famous `Word2Vec` embedding.

---

When people talk about embedding data in vector representation, they really mean `factorization` of the design matrix they explicitly/implicitly construct.

Take `Word2Vec` as an example. The design matrix represents an artificially constructed prediction problem, where words in surrounding context is used to predict the central word (SkipGram). It is equivalent to factorizing a cross-tabbed matrix of context and central words of filled with positive point-wise mutual information. [1]

Now, let's say we would like the answer the question: *how similar a Ford F-150 is to a Toyota Tacoma?*

First, we have to decide if our data allows us to use supervised methods. If yes, then there are a few algorithms like the traditional `Feed-forward neural network` and `factorization machine` that we can use. You can use these algorithms to define similarity of features in one-hot space by using prediction labels, like click on detail page at a car-rental website. Then models with similar vectors means that people click on their detail pages in the same session. That is, the behavior of the response models the similarity of the features.

If your dataset is not labeled, you can still try to predict co-occurrence of features. This is the novelty of `Word2Vec`, namely cleverly defining prediction problems using unlabeled sentence of co-occurring tokens in context windows. In this case, the vectors merely represents co-occurrence of the features. They can be useful as a dimensional reduction technique to extract dense features for another prediction problem down the pipeline.

If you wanna save some brain power, and your features happen to be all factors, you can apply existing algorithms in packages, things like `LDA`, `NMF`, `SVD`, with a loss function for binary classification, such as `hinge loss`. Most programming languages provide their libraries with APIs that consist of a few lines of codes.

All the methods above are `matrix factorization`. There are also deeper, more complex `tensor factorization` methods. But I will let you research on your own on them.

**Reference**

1. http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5477-neural-word-embedding-as-implicit-matrix-factorization.pdf